# Project a new Date into aggregation pipeline using reactivemongo

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I'm trying to craft a new Date value into a projection within a reactivemongo aggregate pipeline.

I have seen other examples where people create this within the mongo shell, like this:

```
db.runCommand({
    "aggregate" : "collectionName", "pipeline": [
       { $project: { exampleDate: new Date() } } 
    ]
})
```

The problem lies in the `new Date()`. With reactivemongo the projection would be a Project object:

```
Project( ("exampleDate", BSONValue) )
```

where the BSONValue can be a BSONString. But that results in mongoDB ignoring such string, since the result will be:

```
{ "aggregate" : "collectionName", "pipeline": [ { $project: { exampleDate: "new Date()" } } ] }
```

Is there any way to insert the `new Date()` without the quotes?

P.S.: I've also tried using `BSONDateTime(0)`
But this results in:

```
{ $date: 0 }
```

Which makes mongoDB throw an invalid `$date` operator exception.

Answer (score 0):

Since the default constructor of the `java.util.Date` class gives the time of the call to the constructor (aka "now"), it seems you are interested in constructing a `BSONDateTime` with the same "now" time. The argument to `BSONDateTime` should be a `Long` value that contains the UTC time in milliseconds. You can get that from `java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis` or from the `java.util.Date.getTime` method.  So, I think what you want is:

```
Project( ("exampleDate", BSONDateTime(System.currentTimeMillis()) )
```

or

```
val now = new java.util.Date()
Project( ("exampleDate", BSONDateTime(now.getTime) )
```

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work, because mongo throws an invalid `$date` operator exception.

Comment: You would need to share the exact code that is producing this for further diagnosis. Could you whittle the problem down into a small project and put it on GitHub? If so, I can probably figure out what the issue is.

Comment: @bILK  did you find the solution for it , adding  new Date() in projection stage